# Is the law of unconscious statistician always true?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable, and $f(x)$ its pmf. Assume that $g(X)$ is a random variable. Then the law of unconscious statistician says
$$E[g(X)]=\sum_xg(x)f(x).$$
Should I interpret this as follows?

> $E[g(X)]$ exists if and only if the sum on the right exists, and in this case they are equal.

By the "sum," I don't mean the limit of partial sums, but the difference of positive and negative parts like in Lebesgue integral:
$$\sum_xg(x)f(x)=\sum_{g(x)>0}g(x)f(x)+\sum_{g(x)<0}g(x)f(x)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Let $Y=g(X)$ and let $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ be the discrete sets of all values that $X$ and $Y$ can take, respectively:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{X} &= \{X(\omega) \in \mathbb{R}: \omega \in \Omega\} \\
\mathcal{Y} &= \{g(X(\omega)) \in \mathbb{R}: \omega \in \Omega \} 
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
\sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}: y\geq0} yP[g(X)=y] &= \sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y} : y\geq0}y \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}:g(x)=y} P[X=x] \\
&= \sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}:y\geq 0} \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}:g(x)=y} g(x) P[X=x] \\
&= \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}:g(x)\geq 0} g(x)P[X=x] 
\end{align}
Similarly,
$$ \sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y} : y<0} y P[g(X)=y] = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}:g(x)<0} g(x) P[X=x]$$
So $E[Y]$ exists and is finite iff the left-hand-sides are both finite iff the right-hand-sides are both finite.